# How does linking a domain and hosting work?

Tags: web-hosting, domains, dns, nameserver

I've looked everywhere for a good explanation of this, but all I get is a tutorial on how to do it instead of what's going on in the background. If someone could go through an example of what's going on in the background when you link a domain to hosting, I'd appreciate it. What exactly is update, where is it updated, and when/in which order? The process I'm referring to is specifying the domain in the hosting settings and specifying the name servers in the domain provider settings.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Website_hosting